# I can ssh out but not in. Reversible?

Tags: ssh, firewall, ssh-tunnel

I have an account on a server inside my corporate network. I also have a VPS from Linode. I can ssh from the corporate server to the Linode VPS or to my home computer with no problems.

But thanks to the corporate firewall, I can't ssh *into* that machine from Linode or from home or from anywhere.

That is:

```
corp --ssh--> home  // works fine

home --ssh--> corp  // blocked
```

Is there a way I can make some sort of reverse tunnel while I'm at work so that I can connect to that machine once I get home?

Note that I'm not asking if it's a good *idea* or if my bosses will freak out and fire me, just... is it possible?

All the computers run Ubuntu and a relatively recent version of SSHD. I can install whatever software I want on the home machine or VPS, but probably am limited to SSH/SSHD and whatever's in the default install of Ubuntu for the corporate server.

Edit: the corp server does have a static IP address and is publicly visible as a web server.

Comment: Is there some reason that you are not working this out with your local site sys admin?  I'm sure they would be happy to help you if this situation is good for the company.  In fact, I would NOT advise trying to circumvent any sort of policy set into effect by the company management.  Open discussion is the best way to get this situation corrected.

Comment: My boss is okay with it. My boss' boss too. Even my boss' boss' boss. The restriction of "no ssh in" is set by corp policy WAY above that. There's no such thing as "open discussion" in this scenario. Believe me, I tried that about eighteen months ago. Your point is well taken, though. Ordinarily that would be a much better solution and it's the route I go most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, take into consideration what mdpc said: do not attempt to circumvent a corporate policy this way. It's not just about your boss freaking out and fire you. If you happen to find yourself in a situation where corporate secrets were released or the network was compromised, it won't help your case if you get found out for doing stuff like this. You can get sued.

Moving on.

What you want really is a reverse SSH tunnel. You can do this from the *forbidden* machine:

```
ssh -NR 8888:localhost:22 you@homemachine.lan
```

Then, at `homemachine.lan`, you only need to do this to access the other machine:

```
ssh corpuser@localhost -p 8888
```

Et voilá, you are ssh'ing to the forbidden machine.

This has been extremely useful for me for the past few years, as a way of traversing NAT. I didn't have access to the router, and I needed to access a machine running behind it. This is how I solved the problem - having the machine start the connection to a trusted host, and connecting locally from there.

I am assuming that machine runs `sshd`, on port 22. Replace usernames as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your Corp Computer is not running through nat with public ip assigned by default to it (something extremely unlikely) you could make a rule with iptables. However your computer is probably running through Firewall and nat , that doesnt allow any kind of listening connection from your Computer to the Internet.

Comment: It's not a corporate "computer"; it's a server with a static IP address. It runs Apache, mostly. Edited the question since that wasn't obvious in the original description.

Comment: So use IPTables to allow traffic from public network to port 22

Comment: This is not a server I maintain. If I could change iptables rules I wouldn't be posting the question.

Comment: So how do you expect to open a connectin to a firewalled machined without permissions?. I mean since port 80 is open, you could try binding the SSH there, however its unsecure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's called reverse ssh tunneling, just google "ssh nat".

If you setup reverse tunnel your corporate computer will have **outgoing** connection to your home PC or another server, but you will be able to use this connection in both directions.

Comment: There's no NAT involved here; the corporate server is a SERVER with a static, publicly visible IP address.

Comment: It's just most easy way to find same answer.